# How to convert X months to Y days in Rails in one step?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a configuration value stored as `3.months`, and another value returning from a calculation as `7.days`.

I need to find their difference. What is the easiest & Railsiest way to normalise them so that I can subtract `7.days` from `3.months`? I can turn .months into days by using .to_i & multiplying by seconds-in-a-day, but it feels pretty long-winded to have to calculate from months to seconds to days like this:

```
  x = (3.months.to_i/86400).days
  => 90 days
  x - 7.days
  => 83 days
```

Is there a snappier way?

Comment: Interestingly, `3.months.days` is valid, but counterintuitive (or even invalid?) given the output: `7776000 days`.

Comment: `3.months.days` gives number of seconds followed by `days`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to keep each term with units of time I would recommend this:

```
 (3.months - 7.days)/1.day
```

I feel like its the cleanest and easiest for another dev to realize what you are trying to describe.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's any better but:

```
end_date = Date.today.advance(months: 3) - 7.days
(end_date - Date.today).to_i #=> 83
```

Answer (score 0):

I'f I understand correctly, you can subtract them one from another like so:

```
(3.months - 7.days)/86400 #=> 83
```

Both months and days methods return an integer of seconds.

Comment: (3.months - 7.days)/86400 #=> -1.days